# Значение (void *)buffer, sizeof(buffer[0])

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Нужно пояснить код на с++ - плохо понимаю!

```
if (input && output) { //если тру
    int totalCount = 0; //счетчик
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //размер буфера 100 байт
    unsigned char CBC = 0; //массив символов(сам шифр-блок)
    //buffer -входные и выходные данные
    while (!feof(input)) { //пока не дошли до конца файла
        int actuallyRead = fread((void * ) buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), BUFFER_SIZE, input); // 1 куда будет прочитан элемент,2-размер каждого прочитанного эл-та

        //3-размер буфера,4 откуда читаем, возвращается количество прочитанных элементов
        cerr << actuallyRead << endl;
        if (mode == ENCRYPT) {
            CBC = encryptCBC(buffer, actuallyRead, key, CBC); //зашифровываем
        } else {
            CBC = decryptCBC(buffer, actuallyRead, key, CBC); //расшифровываем
        }

        fwrite((void * ) buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), actuallyRead, output);

        totalCount += actuallyRead; //в конце увеличиваем кол-во прочитанных элементов на 1
    }
```

интересует вот эта строка=>

```
int actuallyRead = fread((void *)buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), BUFFER_SIZE, input);
```

Почему мы тут ссылаемся на void и что будет записываться на каждом шаге? И что будет возвращать sizeof? 1 байт?

Answer (score 4):

1. size_of  - это оператор (а не функция), который высчитывает размер переменной или даже просто типа данных в байтах.
2. Указатель на буфер приводится к типу void*, потому что такова сигнатура функции fread. Указатель-на-что-угодно, независимо от типа хранимых в нем данных.
3. В каждом шаге будет считываться из файла и записываться максимум BUFFER_SIZE байт. Количество реально прочитанных байт возвращается этой функцией.

Comment: там получается каждый раз sizeof(buffer[0]) считывается из файла по байту и заносится в буфер?

Comment: Нет, она считывает количество элементов, указанное в третьем параметры (в твоем примере BUFFER_SIZE), каждый размером, указанным во втором параметре (т.е. size(buffer[0]), т.е. по одному байту). См. документацию.

Comment: Плюсанул. Считаю, ответ полный.

Comment: ага понятно, просто это часть кода из задания по составлению алгоритма шифрования CBC-(блочного шифрования),Нужно дописать 2 функции, я что-то не могу въехать..

Answer (score 1):

1. ссылаемся на `void*`, т.к. прототип ф-ции именно такой. А его сделали таким, чтобы можно было в нее передавать произвольные области памяти. Сегодня Вы хотите считать массив из 10 элементов `char`. А завтра массив из 100 `int`'ов. Послезавтра - вообще просто нужно будет заполнить поля какой-либо Вашей структуры. А ф-ция библиотечная. И переписывать ее возможности никакой нет. Решение: использовать `void*`. Из минусов - обязанность следить за тем что, куда и в каком кол-ве возлагается на программиста. Напоминаю, что в С++ есть шаблонные ф-ции и возможность перегрузить оператор `>>` для классов `fstream` и `istream`, что проблему с `void*` вроде как снимает.
2. `sizeof(buffer[0])` = `sizeof (unsigned char)` = `1`.